# One Instance of JInternalFrame

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I am working on a swing application using JinternalFrames but when i open one Jinternelframe  it appears in the JDesktopePane and with another click on the same component another instance show up.
i tried to fix this problem by declaring new instance of each JInternalFrame in the Constructor, but in the memory side it's useless, so i am asking if there is any methode to get rid of this issue. 
Thank you a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy-init the frames:

```
private JInternalFrame frame1;
private JInternalFrame frame2;
...

/**
 * invoked when the button used to show the first frame is clicked
 */
private void showFrame1() {
    if (frame1 == null) {
        frame1 = new JInternalFrame();
        // TODO initialize the frame
    }
    // TODO show the frame
}

// same for the other frames
```

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about the singleTone design pattern :D

Comment: As opposed to the Polyphonic design pattern?

Comment: Beware of abusing the singletone pattern: it can quickly lead to cacophony ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is may sample code. hope this help.
Menu action to call internal frame in main application where JdesktopPane in it.

```
 private void YourJinternalFrameMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 

    YourJinternalFrame nw = YourJinternalFrame.getInstance();
    nw.pack();
    //usefull part for you.. if open shows, if not creates new one 
    if (nw.isVisible()) {
    } else {
        desktopPane.add(nw);
        nw.setVisible(true);
    }
    try {

        nw.setMaximum(true);
    } catch (PropertyVetoException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainApplication.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

put this inside of your YourJinternalFrame

```
private static YourJinternalFrame myInstance;

public static YourJinternalFrame getInstance() {
    if (myInstance == null) {
    myInstance = new YourJinternalFrame();
    }
return myInstance;
```